# Keychain Access cannot save CSR to disk

Tags: certificate, keychain, csr

I'm using Keychain Access to generate a CSR file and save it to disk. After pressing save, I cannot find the generated CSR file where I specified, although Keychain Access says "Your certificate request has been created on disk".

I've tried to specify different folder to save the file but failed.

Anyone knows the cause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having this same exact issue. Initially I thought the issue was that I had an existing certificate selected, so I tried just selecting nothing, this also did not work. I finally was able to get it to work by selecting another public key before generating the CSR http://cl.ly/3M3g2S432F3L2n291C0B

Comment: I've already recreated user account in OS, and solved the problem. So I can't try the way you recommended. But thanks all the same.

Comment: selecting another public key before generating the CSR WORKS. Thanks :)